# Get Window Phone Signal C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've already asked this but for iOS and they told me it was impossible.
I migrated to android and Windows Phone.
For Android I've found but not tested this
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/
AFAIK it works. My problem is I'm now testing windows phone but I'm unable to find anything related to this problem. Some people mention WMI and I'm unable to figure out what this is.
Thanks
P.s I,m programming for Windows Phone 8 and 7.1

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/efc34131-6bfa-4ac9-927c-9f6581b9ac35

Comment: @RobertHarvey - that link is for windowsmobile, entirely different platform than Windows Phone 7/8

Comment: I could have used using System.windowsmobile but it's not available for windows phone 8 or 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing we have is [Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and it's parent namespace [Microsoft.Phone.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff707715%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) . These API's don't provide the raw data for the signal but they are able to tell you if the phone is on mobile broadband, the network operator, roaming info, etc. It's designed so that you app can be away of data usage, and intelligently respond when using 3G vs Wifi.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GetSignalBars method in ConnectionProfile, available in Windows Phone 8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getsignalbars.aspx